# get current timestamp from embedded youtube video

Tags: youtube, timestamp, video-streaming, flowplayer

Does anyone know of a FREE plugin for flowplayer that will stream youtube videos?

OR

If I just embed the youtube video in my webpage, is it possible to get the current timestamp of the youtube video.  I want the user to be able to click a button that records the current timestamp of the video being played.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I was looking for the same and have found an answer I believe.

It looks like YouTube has an api for frames:

> https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

and that has a method to grab the current timestamp:

> player.getCurrentTime():Number Returns the elapsed time in seconds
>   since the video started playing.

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_status

Check this out. `player.getCurrentTime():Number` is probably what you are looking for.